# pre load things on JavaFX scene

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

How to load something, like items in ComboBox at JavaFX scene automatically/at start?

I use Java 1.8.0_40

I thought it should be like this, but it won`t working

```
public class Main extends Application {


public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    launch(args);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Print Shop");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();

    Controller.addSelect();
}


public class Controller implements Initializable {

@FXML
private ComboBox<String> firstSortSelect;

public void addSelect() {
    List<String> select = new ArrayList<String>();
    select.add("smts1");
    select.add("smts2");
    for (String cat : select) {
        firstSortSelect.getItems().add(cat);
    }
}
```

The errors is

> Error:(26, 19) java: non-static method addSelect() cannot be referenced from a static context

if I change method to static

> Error:(202, 13) java: non-static variable firstSortSelect cannot be referenced from a static context

I don`t want to create interface/scene dynamically, only data

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, I figured out that myself.

Just use initialize method in Controller

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    addSelect();
}
```